# building a hash lookup table during `git filter-branch` or `git-rebase`

Tags: git, hash, git-filter-branch

I've been using the SHA1 hashes of my commits as references in documentation, etc.  I've realized that if I need to rewrite those commits, I'll need to create a lookup table to correspond the hashes for the original repo with the hashes for the filtered repo.  Since these are effectively UUID's, a simple lookup table would do.

I think that it's relatively straightforward to write a script to do this during a `filter-branch` run; that's not really my question, though if there are some gotchas that make it complicated, I'd certainly like to hear about them.  I'm really wondering **if there are any tools that provide this functionality**, or if there is some sort of convention on where to keep the lookup table/what to call it?  I'd prefer not to do things in a completely idiosyncratic way.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the hashes in documentation in a typical project. This makes you dependent on the full history instead of a single version (if you package the sources you have to package the full repository with them). This is of course beside the point. I'm interested to see if it can be done too :)

Comment: The references themselves are also part of the repo.  It's kind of a long story.... actually 'documentation' is sort of an oversimplification.  I keep my notes on.. well, pretty much everything.. in git.  Referencing commits is useful because a) I am sometimes referring to a set of notes from a note-taking session (eg my notes on `git log`'s `--pickaxe-regex` option); and b) I am sometimes actually referring to a revision in some source code repo; and c) I am sometimes referring to a change in system state (I version some of that stuff in git, too).  But . . .

Comment: . . . it could also be useful to have this kind of cross-reference for use by a bug-tracking / issue-tracking system, eg one that keeps data of the form "fixed in commit $SHA1".  Otherwise I guess you have to update the issue tracker as part of your `filter-branch` script.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the original hashes in commit messages, like git-svn does with revisions.

You could also use [git-notes](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-notes.html) to annotate the new commits with their original hashes. Notes are stored in a special ref, `refs/notes/commits`. That means they will be outside of the annotated branch's history, but that gives you more freedom to change them.

Comment: I think storing the hashes in the commit messages is the most appropriate solution.